# How to highlight a grid view's last inserted record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I wants to highlight the last inserted record on grid view . In my grid view i have a primary key column. newly inserted rows are placing according to the ascending order of this primary key. Now i wants to highlight the last inserted row. from a search i have written like this, but it shows the last row of grid view highlighted., not the newly inserted row. please help. my code is here ,

```
   int lastRowIndex = 0;

     if(!IspostBack)
       {
  string select_string="SELECT student_name,student_id,student_nric,student_group FROM student_details WHERE student_group='"+groups[0].ToString().Trim()+"' ";
        for(int i=1;i<groups.Count;i++)
        {
            select_string+= " or student_group='"+groups[i].ToString().Trim()+"'";    
        }

        if(Session["STUDENT_ID"]!=null)
        {

        for(int i=0;i<student_id_list.Count;i++)
        {
            select_string+= " or student_id='"+student_id_list[i].ToString().Trim()+"'";    

        }
        }
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select_string, con);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        con.Close();


        foreach (GridViewRow grv in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (grv.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (grv.RowIndex > lastRowIndex)
                {
                    lastRowIndex = grv.RowIndex;
                }
            }
        }
        lastRowIndex = GridView2.Rows.Count - 1;

        GridView2.Rows[lastRowIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Plz share the code of inserting data to the gridview and rearranging it ascending order.Based on the inserted Pk value,you can highlight it.

Comment: please check my edited code @ MahaSwetha

Comment: Please specify what your primary key column is. Furthermore, do you know the value of the primary key of the new record, or on what criteria should the record be identified? Is it the highest value, or something?

Comment: primary key is student_id .When i enter the student id to a textbox it should add to the gridview with highlighted this id  @ Kai Hartmann

Comment: @is paging enabled in your gridview?

Comment: no. is that the problem ?  @ naveen

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
lastRowIndex = GridView2.Rows.Count - 1;
```

you always set the lastRowIndex to the same one...

You can use RowsAdded event:

```
private void grv_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    // the new row = e.RowIndex
}
```

Comment: yeahh ..but how can i cahange it based on primarykey value ? @AsfK

Comment: @AsfK: this answer deserve a downvote. `RowsAdded` is a datagridview event. not an asp.net GridView event. please correct... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions you can do
the first one is to create a variable which is accessed in different viewstates like this:

```
private bool AddedSuccesfuly
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)ViewState["flag"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["flag"] = value;
        }
    }
```

next on the pageload you add its value to false since you havent inserted any rows yet
then on the button click event of the insertRow you set its value to true
and on the datarowbound method or in the binding method it doesent matter you at an if statemant like this:

```
if (AddedSuccesfuly == true)
        {
            gridviewname.Rows[gridviewname.Rows.Count1].BackColorSystem.Drawing.Color.Beige;
        }
```

I would also suggest you set the primary key to identity or an auto increment equvalent and not show it in the gridview since there is no need for a student to see its id.